# How do i call a generic method in java using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

As the title says, I am trying to call a generic var-args method using reflection.

The method I am trying to call is `add`, part of `SomeClass<T>`. The concrete instance is `SomeClass<SomeInterface>`, so `add` expects one or more `SomeInterface` objects. Since generics are compile time stuff I do get the method handle with `clazz.getMethod("add", Object[].class)`, but I am unable to pass the argument(s) to that method handle correctly.

```
public class Example1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeInterface si = new SomeInterface() {};
        Object obj = new SomeClass<SomeInterface>(){};
        
        // Knowing the type of obj
        ((SomeClass<SomeInterface>)obj).add(si);
        
        // Dont know the type of obj, but knowing the method name/signature
        Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("add", Object[].class);
        // concrete arguments fail
        try { method.invoke(obj, si); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed2" + ex); }
        try { method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{si}); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed3" + ex); }
        try { method.invoke(obj, new SomeInterface[]{si}); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed4" + ex); }
        try { method.invoke(obj, (Object)si); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed5" + ex); }
        // null works
        try { method.invoke(obj, (Object)null); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed6" + ex); }
        try { method.invoke(obj, (SomeInterface)null); } catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("failed7" + ex); }
    }
}

abstract class SomeClass<T> implements SomeInterface {
    public void add(T... args) { System.out.println("successful");}    
}

interface SomeInterface {    
}
```

Comment: `invoke` takes an array of parameters as it's second argument, so you need `method.invoke(obj, new Object[] {new Object[]{si}});`

Comment: To expand on tgdavies' comment a little: That's basically double-varargs so if you pass `new Object[]{si}` to `invoke(Object o, Object... args)` the resulting call will basically be `add(si)`, i.e. the object containing `si` is unpacked - and since the argument type is `Object[]` passing a single `Object` will fail. If you wrap that into another array (`invoke(obj, new Object[]{newObject[]{si}})`) the unpacking will basically result in `add(new Object[]{si})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the target method is generic; you already correctly identified the erased type for the method lookup. The problem is that the method is a *varargs* method.

You have to pass an array as the method’s first argument, but the `invoke` method also is a *varargs* method. For backward compatibility, passing an array (of a reference type) to a varargs method is treated as if all elements of the array were passed to the method. (On the lower level it’s the other way round; the argument is not put into a new array when it is already an array.)

In other words, there is no difference between

```java
method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{si});
```

and

```java
method.invoke(obj, si);
```

When you cast the array to `Object`, it will be treated like the first argument, as intended:

```java
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SomeInterface si = new SomeInterface() {};
        Object obj = new SomeClass<SomeInterface>(){};
        
        // Knowing the type of obj
        ((SomeClass<SomeInterface>)obj).add(si);

        // Dont know the type of obj, but knowing the method name/signature
        Class<?> clazz = obj.getClass();
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("add", Object[].class);

        method.invoke(obj, (Object)new Object[] { si });

        // correct varargs handling works out-of-the-box with java.lang.invoke

        MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(clazz, "add",
                              MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object[].class));

        mh.invoke(obj, si);
    }
}
```

As an addendum, I include an example of the `java.lang.invoke` package, which does not have this problem, because `MethodHandle`’s `invoke` method is not a *varargs* method but *signature polymorphic* which means , it receives the arguments as passed, without any boxing. The handle also knows that it refers to a *varargs* method and will perform the array creation.